# Hard code an IP in Putty

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I need to be able to provide the putty app via Citrix. The issue is the terminal server is on the prod network which can reach all of our other networks. This would therefore allow a user to putty to any machine they wanted. I'd like to have the putty app launch and go to one specific IP/host that is 'hard-coded' somewhere in the putty configuration. Is this even possible with putty?

Thanks in advance for any guidance that can be provided.

Comment: Putty can also open SSH tunnels etc. You sure could the source and compile a hard coded versionen.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the firewall on the terminal server to only allow outgoing SSH connections to the allowed target. Disable SSH tunneling on the target SSH server.